# Getting Invalid attempt to iterate non-iterable instance for SpringDoc Open API Swagger on IE

Tags: swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-openui

I have recently changed swagger UI from `Springfox` to `SpringDoc OpenApi`.

Swagger is working perfectly fine on `Chrome`.

but on `Internet Explore` I am getting below errors. `My IE version is 11`

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Swagger UI does not support Internet Explorer. From the [documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/#browser-support):

> **Browser support**
>
> Swagger UI works in the latest versions of Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Edge.